Org-sidebar doesn't do what it's supposed to. Should I expect to get it to work?
I'm new to emacs.
I installed the package org-sidebar using (package! org-sidebar) and (use-package org-sidebar) in doom emacs. I then open org-sidebar-tree in my buffer.
According to the documentation on that github page, when I press Return when my cursor is in the side-bar-tree, it should switch the main view to the headline that my cursor is on. Instead it just toggles the todo-state of that headline.
I know that the package hasn't been updated for 6 years, so maybe I just shouldn't expect this to work at all? Does this kind of thing happen when emacs gets updated so old packages no longer work?

I can try reproducing the problem but you'll need to tell me what function you are running: how do you "open org-sidebar-tree in [your] buffer"? Also, which version did you install? I see there is a 2024-01-02 release on melpa-unstable, so it is certainly not the case that it has not been updated in 6 years. Maybe you just need to install the newest version?

@NickD, I apologize, the problem is already fixed, I forgot to mark it as such.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a one-off with no clear causes or cures. It does not appear that it will be helpful to anybody in the future.

@NickD, I agree. not sure how to close my own question.

I fixed it by closing Emacs and restarting it, so I don't know what was going on. Note that reloading the config files with  h r r didn't solve it. I don't know what caused this problem.
